# path based authz on svn not working

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am using `dav_svn_module` and `authz_svn_module` and have setup `AuthzSVNAccessFile` as:

```
[groups]
developer = a_dev,b_dev,c_dev
doc = x_doc,y_doc

[/doc]
@doc = rw
@developer = rw

[/]
@developer = rw
* = r
```

I want members of doc group to have write access to the /doc folder and nothing else, but it is not working. So far doc members can read everything but they cannot write to `/doc` folder.

My server  setup:

```
Linux redhat x86_64 2.6.32-696.3.2.el6.x86_64 
svn version:  1.6.11 
httpd version: 2.2.15
```

My client setup:

```
TortoiseSVN 1.9.3, Build 27038 - 64 Bit
svn command line: svn, version 1.9.3 (r1718519)
```

I'd appreciate any advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The syntax used in the access file is invalid. Since you use `AuthzSVNAccessFile` and not per-repository access files, you must specify the access rules in the following format:

```
[calc:/branches/calc/bug-142]
harry = rw
sally = r
```

Note `calc:` part in the example. It represents the name of the repository. For example, `MyRepository:/trunk`.

You must also double-check that `httpd.conf` file was properly configured.

Read the documentation:

- [SVNBook | Path-based authorization](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html)

> svn version:  1.6.11
>
> httpd version: 2.2.15

You must use up-to-date builds of Apache Subversion and Apache HTTP Server. SVN 1.6 is not supported for more than 5 years.

Comment: You are right, but just to note: for 1.6.* plain `[/path/to/]` section, AFAIR, must work as *:/path/to/ (i.e. "for such path in all and any repo")

Comment: And you *can* mention inheritance of access-level in tree (shorter and readable file as result)

Comment: Unfortunately the latest svn version supported in Redhat is 1.6. Ref: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/646783. I have tried the syntax `[reponame:/path/to/folder]` syntax--this does not make a difference. The issue remains. I have tried many things before posting the question. If httpd.conf is not properly configured, httpd refuses to start. It seems the issue is in `AuthzSVNAccessFile` because simplifying the rules does work--e.g. having only one group--either `doc` or `dev`--with pure `r` or pure `rw` rights